# Installing eggs theme in django-oscar

Tags: python, themes, django-oscar

I found a theme for django-oscar here :
https://github.com/eggforsale/oscar-eggs-theme
But there is no documentation available to install it.
I tried replacing the appropriate files in the oscar/templates directory but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

be sure you have updated the oscar template folder in the setting.py as the docs :

```
    location = lambda x: os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '..', x)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            location('templates'), # templates directory of the project
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                ...
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/how_to_handle_statics.html